# How to send data in Link component to other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build a basic app. I have a Questions page and I keep the answers of the questions in answers array. After the test I want to send user to Results page with Link for see the score. So I need the use answers array in the Results component but when I try this I just get an empty array. It's obvious there is a mistake in my Routing or something. I cropped to parts that I thougt unnecessary. If you need more info about that just let me know.
Here is my App.js

```
function App() {
  const [answers,setAnswers]=React.useState();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
          <Route exact path="/questions" element={<Questions />} />
          <Route exact path='/results' element={<Results state={answers}/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Questions.js

```
function Questions() {
const [answers, setAnswers] = React.useState([]);
return(
        <div>
            <h1>Questions</h1>
            <Link to={{pathname:"/results"}} state={answers}>
                Go to Results
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Results.js

```
function Results(props){
    const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([props.state]);
    console.log(answers)
    return(
        <div>
            Result Page
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why would you assign props to state?

Comment: I thought I can reach the answers from Questions page that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't add data from props to state, it will only make it harder

https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-glitter-546kuv?file=/src/App.js

Pass state to the components in `App`

```
export default function App() {
  const [answers, setAnswers] = React.useState([]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            element={<Questions setAnswers={setAnswers} />}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/results"
            element={<Results answers={answers} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Show answers in `Results`

```
function Results({ answers }) {
  return (
    <div>
      Result Page
      {answers.map((q) => (
        <p>{q}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```